# How i can prepare my own dataset (thousand of images) in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have some thousands of images in .PNG format. The labels for these png files are stored in txt file.
PNG files names are like 1.png, 2.png, 3.png and so on...
TXT file contains labels separated by new lines (Each line contains a single lable)

How can I prepare them for use in tensorflow?

Once prepared/loaded, I want to train a CNN in tensorflow by using the images mentioned. 
It will be highly appreciated If someone can give specific examples of reading png and txt files in tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna check out tensorflow `slim` library, including its `dataset` class and use of `data_set_data_provider.py`

slim: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.11/tensorflow/contrib/slim

dataset:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.11/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/data

Comment: Thanks for your reply but since i am new, it is really hard for me to understand this from the above mentioned links. It will be highly appreciated If someone can give specific examples of reading png and txt files.